# Can i give spaces between the bar rectangles without adjusting the height attribute?

Tags: d3.js

In my fiddle having horizontal bar graph; i want to give more space between the bars .[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rBfy5/2174/). I can tamper with the height attribute(line:101) and reduce the bar heights so that the space seems increased But i  donot want to change their height. How can i increase the space between bars without changing their height?

Code for the rectangles

```
 rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
    return d;
})
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) {
    return xScale(d.x0);
})
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
})
    .attr('height', function (d) {
    return yScale.rangeBand();
})
    .attr('width', function (d) {
    return xScale(d.x);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already doing it in your code. When you write:

```
yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(months)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);
```

That second argument in `rangeRoundBands` is the padding between the bars:

```
ordinal.rangeRoundBands(interval[, padding[, outerPadding]])
```

So, you just need to tweak that value. Check this fiddle, using `0.5`: https://jsfiddle.net/catbu2oz/

But if you're talking about keeping *the same height in pixels*, there is only one solution: hardcoding the height value of the bars and increasing the range of the scale, as in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xakLhfo/